# Cannot debug error message for psycopg2 with django and postgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2, archlinux

I am trying to create a postgreSQL database connected to a django web app using psycopg2. I am recieving the following error when I run `python manage.py migrate`

```
(temp-python) ❯ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/git-repos/MyApp/temp-python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    import psycopg2 as Database
  File "~/git-repos/MyApp/temp-python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: ~/git-repos/MyApp/temp-python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libresolv-2-c4c53def.5.so: symbol __res_maybe_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "~/git-repos/MyApp/temp-python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "~/git-repos/MyApp/temp-python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "~/git-repos/MyApp/temp-python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "~/git-repos/MyApp/temp-python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "~/git-repos/MyApp/temp-python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "~/git-repos/MyApp/temp-python/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "~/git-repos/MyApp/connecting/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "~/git-repos/MyApp/temp-python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "~/git-repos/MyApp/temp-python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "~/git-repos/MyApp/temp-python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 119, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "~/git-repos/MyApp/temp-python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 316, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "~/git-repos/MyApp/temp-python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "~/git-repos/MyApp/temp-python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "~/git-repos/MyApp/temp-python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "~/git-repos/MyApp/temp-python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "~/git-repos/MyApp/temp-python/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "~/git-repos/MyApp/temp-python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: ~/git-repos/MyApp/temp-python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libresolv-2-c4c53def.5.so: symbol __res_maybe_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
```

I'm running arch linux and don't really know where to begin with debugging this error, thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: did you modify your settings.py by adding the postgres module?

Comment: Do you know which version of psycopg2 you're using?  [There was a known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966278/psycopg2-import-error-when-ubuntu-upgraded-to-17-10-from-17-04) with the Glibc wheel on a few systems (have seen it on debian, arch and ubuntu).   It should have been fixed in [2.2 though](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2-wheels/issues/2)

Comment: @Withnail I clicked your link [here](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2-wheels/issues/2#issuecomment-324682820) and followed the advice given in [this comment](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2-wheels/issues/2#issuecomment-324682820). The `python manage.py migrate` command now works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries - I've put this as an answer, if you'd like to accept it and help the people who come after you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a known bug on [psycopg2 versions prior to 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966278/psycopg2-import-error-when-ubuntu-upgraded-to-17-10-from-17-04).

That gives you the option of either [restarting it, as it may be a runtime problem](https://lists.debian.org/debian-glibc/2005/08/msg00363.html), or alternatively you can reinstall using the `--no-binary psycopg2` command, which will prevent it using the wheel, per the last comment in that thread.